# How to run cmder from start menu

Tags: windows-10, cmder

I have been vexed by what I felt should be an easy issue to solve. I have been trying to run the cmder executable from the start menu. But when I type the Cmder in the Run box, Cmder.exe does not show up in the list

[image]

But I can see from the cmd that Cmder.exe is present and when I run that exe in cmd , Cmder opens up.

[image]

Is there some reason that Cmder.exe does not appear in my start/run command?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason for this is that Cmder isn't installed like a typical Windows application.

The solution is to add Cmder to your computer's path.  See [Henrik Sommerfeld's blog post](http://henrik.sommerfeld.nu/making-cmder-findable-by-windows-search/).

Additionally, if you're interested in learning more about what is being used for your searches, click the `Filters` button. See image below:

[image: Filter button]

Comment: Why did Henrik Sommerfeld put cmder in C:\bin\cmder? Is there any kind of wider accepted best practice that suggests we should do that?

Comment: No, there's no convention, this is one of the things I like about cmder is that you can place it any directory you want.  I suspect, like myself, Henrik did it to have a short path to cmder (save on typing).  I personally put it in `c:\app\cmder`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Start Menu, install [Keypirinha](https://keypirinha.com/). Then add the folder where you store Cmder and similar tools, to the Keypirinha and you can get rid of the Start Menu.
Keypirinha is faster and much more flexible than the Start Menu - e.g. let you pick the apps from somewhere on your machine.

I have a lot of XCopy-deployable tools like Cmder (and Keypirinha too) in an "Application" Git repository. If I have to provision a new developer machine with all the beloved developer tools, now the fast way is:

1. install [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)
2. install [Git Extensions via Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/gitextensions)
3. clone my "Application" Git repository

This a done in less than 10 minutes and it covers 95% of my toolset.

Answer (score 0):

To have CMDER on Windows Context Menu (right click) wherever you want.

1. Open a terminal as an Administrator
2. Navigate to the directory you have placed Cmder
3. Execute `.\cmder.exe /REGISTER ALL`

If you get a message "Access Denied" ensure you are executing the command in an Administrator prompt.
In a file explorer window right click in or on a directory to see "Cmder Here" in the context menu.
From: https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder#shortcut-to-open-cmder-in-a-chosen-folder
Tip: put the CMDER files in c:\Program Files\CMDER